# Connecting Mysql Database on EC2 from Java SE Application

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-ec2

I am just starting with this kind of topic, I really apreciate any help.

I am trying to connect to a Mysql Database running on an AWS EC2 instance from a simple Java stand alone application, I  already could connect from my  java program to  other  mysql databases throught jConnector using the  just Host, Port, user and password. Besides I can connect from mySql Workbench to my EC2 database but I had to use the AWS Key pair file.

```
java.sql.Connection myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://AWS_HOST:3306/Clientes?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=false","root","password");
```

Is it possible connecting using the key pair file just with JConnector?

or what other knowledge or resourse is needed?

I would apreciate an example or tips in order to  learn what is needed to connect   a java program using an AWS key pair file.

Comment: There are restrictions from aws side, please check
1. the EC2 security groups have a rule allowing remote access
2. also mysql root user have to be granted for remote access

Comment: @edwgiz thanks for you help, I assumed that root user had all permissions and then I should use the aws key pair file in order to connect to the EC2 database  .Finally, I created a new user in the database and configured remote access and then my java application successfully connected